# How to convert a String in java with 1s and 0s to corresponding ASCII value?

Tags: java, string, ascii

How do one  convert a String in java with 1 and 0s to corresponding ASCII value?

Lets say I have

```
String str = "01101110";
```

How do I convert it to be its corresponding 'n' so I can print n?

```
System.out.printl(str.toCorrespondingAscii());//output n
```

Comment: You have to convert binary to decimal and print it as char

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int value = Integer.parseInt("01101110", 2); //2 for binary
System.out.println(value);  // To print ascii

char digit = (char) value;
System.out.println(digit);  // To print n
```

Comment: I think the OP wants the number `n` actually.